# Changing the position of publisher, location and separate the edition via comma

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, citing

I would like to follow the guidelines of my supervisor. He tolds me to cite a book as follows …, Edition., Publisher, Location.

The Default citation with the following preamble is

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage
[style=authoryear,labelnumber,
sorting=nyt,maxbibnames=9,maxcitenames=2,uniquelist=false, backend=biber, 
doi=false,isbn=false,url=false,
uniquename=false,bibencoding=utf8, date=year, giveninits=true, terseinits=false]
{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}


\begin{filecontents}{\jobname2.bib}
@Book{Wooldrige2013,
  author    = {Wooldridge, Jeffrey},
  title     = {Introductory econometrics : a modern approach},
  year      = {2013},
  edition   = {5},
  publisher = {Cengage Learning},
  location  = {Mason, USA},

}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname2.bib} 

\begin{document}
\textcite{Wooldrige2013}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

this one

[image]

correct Version should be:

5. Aufl., Cengage Learning, Mason, USA.

Comment: Please show us a minimal working example that reproduces the output shown in the screenshot like in your last questions. That makes it much easier to get started, and maybe the code there reveals some things that need to be taken into consideration when answering your question. If anything, just provide the MWE so I don't have to re-type the `.bib` entry.

Comment: Edited, the post

Comment: What should happen to punctuation after "Aufl." when there are other fields present which come in between `edition` and `publisher`? (e.g., in `authoryear` style this includes: `volume` and `part` (if there is no `maintitle`), `volumes`, `series`, `number`, and `note`.

Comment: For books I only use the information listed above. So there will be nothing between the word "Aufl." and Edition/Publisher.

Comment: It just should be the case, that there is no edition

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bit tricky. `biblatex`'s punctuation tracker that typesets the punctuation works best with the same type of punctuation in all places. Since in the bibliography driver `edition` and the `publisher`/`location`/`date` blocks are separated a bit (in particular there are fields that could be printed in between, e.g. `note`, `series`+`number`, `volumes`, ...), it can be hard to get the punctuation right.

The simplest solution I could find was using [`biblatex-ext`](https://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-ext)

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=ext-authoryear,
sorting=nyt,maxbibnames=9,maxcitenames=2,uniquelist=false, backend=biber, 
doi=false,isbn=false,url=false,
uniquename=false, date=year, giveninits=true]
{biblatex}

\renewcommand*{\subtitlepunct}{\addcolon\space}

\renewbibmacro{edition}{}
\renewbibmacro*{pubinstorg+location+date}[1]{%
  \printfield{edition}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \printlist{#1}%
  \setunit*{\publocdelim}%
  \printlist{location}%
  \setunit*{\pubdatedelim}%
  \usebibmacro{date}%
  \newunit}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname2.bib}
@Book{Wooldrige2013,
  author    = {Wooldridge, Jeffrey M.},
  title     = {Introductory Econometrics},
  subtitle  = {A Modern Approach},
  year      = {2013},
  edition   = {5},
  publisher = {Cengage Learning},
  location  = {Mason, USA},

}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname2.bib} 

\begin{document}
\textcite{Wooldrige2013}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Wooldridge, J. M. (2013). Introductory Econometrics: A Modern Approach. 5. Aufl., Cengage Learning, Mason, USA.]

Comment: Awesome ! Just one question. Why are you so experienced with biblatex ?

Comment: @Vala Not enough real hobbies...

Comment: Was testing the code, results in "Package biblatex Error: Style 'ext-authoryear' not found." Did I have to add some extended packages ?

Comment: @Vala You need to install `biblatex-ext` (https://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-ext). That package should be available in all up-to-date distributions (MikTeX 2.9 and TeX live >= 2018), so you should not have to install it manually. What TeX distribution do you use (how did you install TeX)?

Comment: MiKTeX 2.9, a bit confusing

Comment: @Vala Not at all. You will have to install that package. You should be able to do that using the MikTeX Console: https://miktex.org/howto/miktex-console. Open the Console and click on *Tasks > Update package database* in the menu. Then wait until the little status bar at the bottom does not read "Updating the package database ..." any more (this might take a while). If the database is updated, click on *Packages* on the right and search for `biblatex-ext` and install it. If you have a few days until your deadline you should also consider running the update procedure afterwards (at least twice)

Comment: I'm speechless, you're awesome ! After my thesis I'll spend some hours into  Latex to learn some deeper stuff such as defining own macros. Then I don't always have to ask :)